# Product of Fixed points and kernel of Frobenius morphism

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

If $G$ is a reductive algebraic group over an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic $p$, and $G$ is defined over the prime field, we have the Frobenius morphism $F: G\to G$, which for each positive number $r$ leads to two subgroups of $G$, namely $G_r$ which is the kernel of the $r$'th iteration of $F$, and $G^{F^r}$ which is the fixed points of the same.

Now, $G^{F^r}$ normalizes $G_r$ (since $G_r$ is normal in $G$), and they clearly intersect trivially. So in $G$ the subgroup $G^{F^r}G_r$ is a semidirect product.

My question is whether this subgroup and its representations has been studied. We certainly know some of its irreducible representations, as any irreducible representation of $G_r$ or $G^{F^r}$ extend to $G$ (and they even have the same irreducibles when these are seen as $G$-modules). So one of the main questions would be whether there are any other irreducible representations of this group.

Of course, one could also consider $G^{F^r}G_{r'}$ with $r\neq r'$ and ask the same questions.

The reason I am interested in this group is that it seems like it might provide a more direct link between the representation theories of $G_r$ and $G^{F^r}$, which are certainly very similar.

It might also provide an additional stepping stone for comparing the representation theories of $G_r$ or $G^{F^r}$ with that of $G$, since one of the ways one often does such comparison is via the induction from either $G_r$ or $G^{F^r}$ to $G$, and both of these factor through this subgroup.

(I asked this question in the representation theory chat room, trying to get the discussion going, but I realized it was focused enough that it might as well be an actual question here).

Comment: At first sight your formulation looks rather confusing, since you attempt to mix finite groups with finite group schemes.   Also, it is not so much irreducible modules which raise questions in these two settings, but rather projective modules and  cohomol/ogy.   Have you consulted local experts?

Comment: @JimHumphreys By subgroup I mean subgroup scheme, and I suppose you are right that the question of projectives might well be a lot more interesting. I asked my advisor (Henning Haahr Andersen), and he had not heard of any study of this subgroup. The question may well be too naive to lead anywhere.

Comment: Maybe what you mean by Frobenius is not the standard thing, as the standard Frobenius only maps $G$ to itself if $G$ is defined over the prime field.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Sorry, I forgot to add the assumption that the group is defined over the prime field.

Comment: I definitely talked about this with Brian Parshall and Len Scott at one point. I think we even found a minor use for it. (Too minor to be worth following up.) They had someone in mind who'd worked with such things. I'll email them. As you say, the simples must be easy to work out.

Comment: @Tobias: Sorry, I still can't make sense of what you've written.   The group of points over a finite field is not actually a "group scheme"; it's just an ordinary finite group.   Look again at what goes into Jantzen's constructions of "mixed" group schemes involving tori or Borel subgroups.

Comment: @JimHumphreys I suppose it is the notation that is to blame here. I don't mean the points over the finite field, but rather the fixed points of the $r$'th iterate of $F$ (as a morphism of schemes), which is a subgroup scheme (and the points over the finite field are then identified with the points of this group scheme over the base field). I will change the notation to reflect this.

Comment: While they get back to me, take a look at Suslin's paper `Detection theorem for finite group schemes' in JPAA. He considers finite groups schemes of the sort you're thinking about in there (though it looks like the finite bit is always a p-group). Maybe chasing some of the references will bring further windfall.

Comment: The names that Brian thought of were Carlson, Friedlander, Suslin, Pevtsova and Witherspoon (maybe) as people who have worked on finite group schemes in this sort of direction. So I'd check out those guys. My guess is you've got a free run at this.